# Need suggestion for finding online user in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to ROR. I am trying to find the online users in my rails application . 
 I came up with an idea but not sure whether thats an better option . Please someone give suggestions in  my idea.

My Idea is,

Maintaining a Table which contains fields(id,user_id,last_pinged_at)
and this last_pinged_at to be updated at each time till the user has logged in.

ANd with this last_pinged_at value to find the user is in online or not?

Is the above idea is a better option  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your suggestion is fine, though 'last_seen_at' is a better name than 'last_pinged_at' in my opinion: "last_pinged_at" makes it sound like you are pinging them, ie sending a ping to their ip address, which you're not.

Many login/authentication systems, eg Authlogic, do this as a matter of course.  You've got two main options really depending on how up to date you want your last_seen_at field to be.

a) update a user's last_seen_at when they log in.  If users can stay logged in for several days this isn't very useful.

b) update a user's last_seen_at on every page load (this is what stack overflow does - click on your name at the top of the page and it will say 'last seen 0 secs ago') .  This will keep the data very up to date.  The simplest way to do this is to just put a method in a before filter in application controller to set current_user (which is usually stored in an instance variable @current_user) and update the current user's last_seen_at field to Time.now.

c) Have some js which sends an 'i'm still here' message to the server every five seconds or so.  This will keep the time really up to date but is obviously an extra server load.

With respect to "ANd with this last_pinged_at value to find the user is in online or not?":  It depends on whether you really need to know if they are online, ie whether it's crucial to your website's "business model".  The rails server is stateless and there's no concept of an active connection - just a series of discrete requests.  So, the best you can really say is "I have evidence, from a request, that the user was logged in recently".  How recent you need that to be determines which type of approach you need.

For example, if you are building a chat room type of thing, you really do need to know when someone closes the window as that effectively logs them out of the chat.  In that case, i wouldn't try to catch the action of them actually leaving (as Mytest suggests) as there are too many ways to do it (eg closing the browser) - it's going to be hard to get it to be really reliable.  I would just do the polling approach, where they send a background request every five seconds for example.  In that case, you could have a rule that says that if last_seen_at is more than ten seconds ago then they are deemed to have logged out.

Comment: I have added an action in my application controller to update my last_active field in my Users table and its updating well. But i am having a doubt in the User model . I am having an action in my User model def online? self.last_active > 10.minutes.ago  end

Comment: Which checks the user who are all online for the past 10 mins . But its not including whether the user has logged out .. How to check this ??

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is to have a ping back when the user closes the browser, or navigates away from the site.

There are two methods to do this.

- The first is quite a hack, which is to have your site in a frame, and when the outer page receives a window.onbeforeunload event, you know they are leaving your site. You can use this event to send an AJAX ping to your server telling them you have left
- alternatively, you can catch all clicks on your site, and on any onbeforeunload events, if they are not associated with a recent click, then you know they are leaving your site. This however can be unreliable if the user leaves your site during a page load following a click.

I would suggest your approach is better though, as it is more reliable, although less accurate. Having a record of last activity, and if over a certain length of time, the user is deemed logged out (just like a Session would do in a statefull application world).